# Convert Pandas Dataframe to numpy for sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I am new to python and sklearn. I have a pandas data frame of titanic dataset. I want it to use for sklearn logistic prediction.

I tried the following

```
data_np = data.astype(np.int32).values
```

But not working. I want to make use of different features in the dataset like 'Pclass', "Age", 'Sex' etc ...

I want to convert the entire data , as well as single columns say data["Age"] to sklearn numpy format . Any help .

Comment: Can you post your code which isn't working, pandas dfs are compatible with sklearn so it's unnecessary to convert the data, sometimes you may need to access the data as nunpy arrays which can be done just using `.values`

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at `sklearn-pandas` (https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas) which provides a bridge between both

Comment: I convert graphlab SFrame to pandas. code is too big. The problem is, in the Sex category iam passing to sklearn fit function , it has 'male' and 'female' values.

Comment: I am getting the following error ....     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: male

Comment: sklearn expects the values to be floats generally, as such you can't pass strings as values so you'll have to convert the strings to numeric values such as `0` and `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem. The main reason is lack of familiarity with numpy.

To convert the features of data['Sex'] into bumpy array use the following code.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

enc = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder = enc.fit(p_train['Sex'])
print "Categorical classes:", label_encoder.classes_
integer_classes = label_encoder.transform(label_encoder.classes_)
print "Integer classes:", integer_classes
x_train = label_encoder.transform(p_train['Sex'])
x_test = label_encoder.transform(p_test['Sex'])

x_train = x_train[:,np.newaxis]
x_test = x_test[:,np.newaxis]
```

Here, we are basically converting 'male' and 'female' categorical data into integer classes of 0 and 1. This is essentials sclera expects everything to be float. The np.newaxis is used to convert the shape of x_train from (n_features,) to (n_features,1). Otherwise while fitting the model you will have another error of incompatible shapes.

Comment: This is a big friction between pandas and numpy. I don't understand why this were not simplified. I am strong in modeling and linear algebra but waste so much time on these details about how to extract the pandas data and format it in a way sklearn will accept.

Answer (score 4):

Categorical variables like 'Sex' and 'Embarked' need to be one-hot-encoded to be able to use them in a `LogisticRegression` model. With pandas you can use the `get_dummies(data['Sex'])`.

There is a full tutorial that covers specifically this issue on the same dataset here:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ogrisel/parallel_ml_tutorial/blob/master/rendered_notebooks/04%20-%20Pandas%20and%20Heterogeneous%20Data%20Modeling.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

To process your numerical *and* non-numerical data, consider using [scikit-learn LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), which allows you to

> Encode labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1.

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29187634/1569064